# Error uploading PDF-like object to s3 bucket from Streamlit

Tags: python, pdf, amazon-s3, streamlit

I have build a streamlit app that takes PDF as an input. After everything is done I want to save/upload the initial pdf file to s3 bucket for check in the future.

```
st.markdown =('# Imdocker pull mysql/mysql-server:latestport your PDF file')

pdf = st.file_uploader(label='Drag the PDF file here. Limit 100MB')
if pdf is not None:
    text = TextExtraction.extract_text(pdf)
```

the bluh bluh the script that does nothing with pdf.

In the end I have:

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='ams3',
    aws_access_key_id='5LVOTUJBAAJ2IIMGVBJV',
    aws_secret_access_key='4SwvDZyDCbcmxoup6BPLImYc4aSeWuGLKECRTdgIn0Y',
)

bucket_name = 'mirai-pdf-private-stage'
print(pdf)
print(type(pdf))
pdf.seek(0)
name = 'pdf_' + str(id) + '.pdf'
print(name)
s3.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_fileobj(pdf, 'pdf_storage', name)
```

get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 563, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "/app/main.py", line 124, in <module>
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_fileobj(pdf, 'pdf_storage', name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 678, in bucket_upload_fileobj
    return self.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 629, in upload_fileobj
    future = manager.upload(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/s3transfer/manager.py", line 321, in upload
    self._validate_all_known_args(extra_args, self.ALLOWED_UPLOAD_ARGS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/s3transfer/manager.py", line 500, in _validate_all_known_args
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Invalid extra_args key 'p', must be one of: ACL, CacheControl, ChecksumAlgorithm, ContentDisposition, ContentEncoding, ContentLanguage, ContentType, ExpectedBucketOwner, Expires, GrantFullControl, GrantRead, GrantReadACP, GrantWriteACP, Metadata, ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus, ObjectLockMode, ObjectLockRetainUntilDate, RequestPayer, ServerSideEncryption, StorageClass, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey, SSECustomerKeyMD5, SSEKMSKeyId, SSEKMSEncryptionContext, Tagging, WebsiteRedirectLocation
```

I couldn't find anything online that does similar or fixes my issue.

I tried changing:

```
s3.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_fileobj(pdf, 'pdf_storage', name)
```

to

```
s3.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_fileobj(pdf, 'pdf_storage', name, extra_arg=None)
```

and get unexpected argument error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you posted this on the Streamlit forum and it was answered there. Sharing the response below.

> If you use boto3.client instead of resource, and s3.upload_fileobj
> instead of s3.Bucket.upload_fileobj, it should work.

```
import boto3
import streamlit as st

pdf = st.file_uploader(label="Drag the PDF file here. Limit 100MB")
if pdf is not None:
    s3 = boto3.client(
        service_name="s3",
        region_name="xxx",
        aws_access_key_id="xxx",
        aws_secret_access_key="xxx",
    )

id = 123
bucket_name = "xxx"
print(pdf)
print(type(pdf))
pdf.seek(0)
name = "pdf_" + str(id) + ".pdf"
print(name)
s3.upload_fileobj(pdf, "pdf_storage", name)
```